# Are async* streams automatically closed when there's no more reference to it?

Tags: dart

Consider this program:

```
import 'dart:async';

Stream<int> counter() async* {
  for (int i = 0; true; i++) {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    print('counter $i');
    yield i;
  }
}

Future<void> main() async {
  await for (var value in counter()) {
    print(value);
    if (value == 5) {
      break;
    }
  }
  // continue to do stuff
}
```

This will print the following:

```
counter 0
0
counter 1
1
counter 2
2
counter 3
3
counter 4
4
counter 5
5
counter 6
```

The thing is, the stream created by `counter()` never actually finish. It seems to block at on `yield` at the 6th step.

Does this mean that I have potentially memory leak? Or does dart understand that this stream is not listened anymore and there's no more reference to it; therefore correctly free the resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, you should not have any memory leak.

When the `await for` loop breaks, it cancels the stream-subscription. That will exit the `counter` function at the next `yield` (an `async*` function checks whether it's been cancelled at a `yield`, and if so, it acts as a `return` instead).

You can add a `try {} finally {}` around the code if you want to do clean-up when the stream is cancelled. The finally block will run, just as if the `yield` had been a normal `return;`. The `cancel` operation called by the `await for` loop exit *should* wait for the clean-up to complete (for the `async*` function to properly return) before continuing.

When the function returns, there is no timer running, the stream subscription is cancelled, and nobody is hanging on to anything.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted to know. But this raise a second question: What if at some point the `counter` function wanted to do some cleanup? Is there any way for it to catch such abort?